# Prove $\lbrace A_n : n \in \mathbb{Z}\rbrace$ is a partition of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: equivalence-relations, set-partition

Dr. Pinter's "A Book of Abstract Algebra" presents the following exercise:

> Prove that each of the following is a partition of the indicated set. Then describe the equivalence relation with that partition.
>
> For each integer $n$, let $A_n = \lbrace x \in \mathbb{Q} : n \leqslant x < n + 1\rbrace$. Prove $\lbrace A_n : n \in \mathbb{Z}\rbrace$ is a partition of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Here's the picture that I have of $A_n, \mathbb{Q}, \text{ and } \mathbb{Z}$:

[image]

Please comment on my picture, as well as guide me on how to complete this proof.

Comment: Your picture is not correct. For example: $n+\frac{1}{2} \in A_n$ but $n+\frac{1}{2} \not\in \mathbb{Z}$, for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your picture shows $A_n$ as a subset of $\Bbb Z$, which is not true for any $n$: the only integer in $A_n$ is the integer $n$ itself. The rest of $A_n$ consists of the rational numbers between $n$ and $n+1$.

Here’s a better picture:

```
 --)[-------)[-------)[-------)[-------)[-------)[-------)[-------)[-----  
   -2       -1        0        1        2        3        4        5
```

the line represents $\Bbb Q$, and the interval shown as

```
                                    [-------)  
                                    n      n+1
```

represents $A_n$.

Comment: Thank you, Professor, for that clear picture. Given that $A_n$ consists of `[n-----n+1)`, per your diagram, is that a proof that $A_n$ is a partition of $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @Kevin: You’re welcome. It’s not in itself a proof, but it points the way to one. To show that $\{A_n:n\in\Bbb Z\}$ is a partition of $\Bbb Q$, you must show two things. (1) For each $q\in\Bbb Q$ there is an $n\in\Bbb Z$ such that $q\in A_n$. (HINT: The floor, or greatest integer, function.) (2) If $m,n\in\Bbb Z$, and $m\ne n$, then $A_m\cap A_n=\varnothing$. (HINT: Assume that $m<n$. If $q\in A_m$, then $q<m+1\ldots\;$.)